# Phone gap build not activating my windows phone application certificate

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-build

I am developing a Windows Phone application. When I fetch it from my git to phonegap build website, to add certificate it asks for my publisher ID. I type it in and press submit, it submits successfully but when i try to select certificates, it doesnt show any certificates to select from. 
[image]
On the other hand, if i go to my account settings and view certificates, it shows my certificates there.

Does anyone know whats going on and what can I do?
[image]

Comment: kindly write solution if you found it. its my humble request

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you still need this but try downgrading the phonegap version to cli-6.0.0. See http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/signing/windows/.

From the docs:
Windows 8/8.1 - use cli-6.0.0

**Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Signing**

1. Log into the Windows Dev Center, and click Dashboard in the top right.
2. Click Account Settings.
3. Copy the Windows Publisher ID field.
4. Add the Publisher ID to your Signing Keys in your PhoneGap Build Account Settings.
5. Build your app using the newly added Windows Publisher ID, selected in a dropdown in your App details.
6. Upload the resulting xap/appx file to the Windows Dev Center.

Comment: This could be a genuinely *great* answer, as the link provides help and details what to do in the OP's issue.  However, as with most links, it is possible it could eventually go dead and then this answer wouldn't be useful.  We prefer you provide some basic detail (from the page), within the answer itself, along with the link.

Comment: @gravity thanks! Edited the answer to provide a bit more detail.